# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer when deploying web project on WebLogic

Tags: java, maven, servlets, weblogic

I am trying to deploy my `web application` (in the form of an `.ear` file) on `weblogic` server, using the `weblogic` administration console. when I add my ear to the console, I get the following error -

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
```

I have already tried quite a few things form the other threads that I could find. But somehow they dont seem to be helping.

Following is the `pom.xml` for my module -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>ParentModule</groupId>
<artifactId>ParentModule</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>WARModule</artifactId>  
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>WARModule Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>WARModule</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version> <!-- Put here the version of your Java EE app, in my case 7.0 -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>
```

Following are the `dependencies` that are added in my module - 
[image]

And this is what the weblogic console looks like when I add my project and try to run it.

[image]

Any help on how to get rid of this is much appreciated, It's been a while since I'm stuck with this!

Also, this is what my `WEB-INF/lib` folder looks like - [image]

Comment: Did you check the required jersy jars inside WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: they do seem to be there. Edited my question though. Please take a look. @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne

Comment: Can you add the http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.6 and check.

Comment: Can you remove your jersey 1.x dependencies from your pom.xml first? They have a different package structure than Jersey 2!

Comment: Removed the `1.x dependencies`, @aksappy

Comment: It still gives me the same error even after I add what you suggested @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne

Comment: Check whether your WEB-INF do not contain any 1.x jersey jar files. Also check whether the version of weblogic supports the Jersey 2. If you find no issues, try removing the web.xml configuration of Jersey and add a programmatic declaration of application.

Comment: From https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24494/toc.htm#NOTES306 it is clear that weblogic 12 c ( which I am using) does not support jersey 2. It talks about supporting version Jersey Jax-RS version 1.9. @aksappy

Comment: Then remove all 2.x dependencies, add the required 1.x dependencies. Change your web.xml to pick up 1.x jersey resources.

Comment: trying that, @aksappy will let you know if I happen to get stuck with that